# Template function/class implicit instantiation rules used in stateful meta programming

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, template-meta-programming

I am working with a code example concerning stateful meta programming.
The original code example can be found from this link: http://b.atch.se/posts/non-constant-constant-expressions/#appendix-clang-workaround

In order to understand this technique, I try to modify the code example each time a bit. Here follows the latest version which still works:

```
constexpr int adl_flag(int);

template <class Tag> struct writer {
  friend constexpr int adl_flag(int) {
    return 0;
  }
};

template <int = adl_flag(0)> constexpr bool is_flag_usable(int) {
  return true;
}

constexpr bool is_flag_usable (...) {
  return false;
}

template <
  class Tag = int,
  bool    B = is_flag_usable(0),
  int       = sizeof (writer<Tag>) // replace Tag with int
>
constexpr int f() {
  return B;
}

int main() {
  constexpr int a = f();
  constexpr int b = f();

  static_assert(a != b, "fail");

  return 0;
}
```

To me, it seems trivial to replace Tag with int. But this replacement in fact make the `static_assert fail`.

I guess this is because the compiler no longer implicitly instantiate f for the second call :

```
constexpr int b = f();
```

But the template type parameter Tag seems has nothing to do with this. Can somebody explain what's actually going on here, please.

The compiler I used is `g++ 5.4.1`. Compiling with `-std=gnu++14`.

Comment: Given how much the committee [hates this](https://wg21.link/CWG2118), I don't see spending time on this as a particularly useful endeavor.

Comment: @T.C. what a killjoy :(

Comment: @T.C. I agree. The author of the blog also declare that this is "just another clever hack, diving into the dark corners of C++". I only treat this as some interesting phenomenon which helps me with learning c++.

Comment: Could this technique be used to implement some form of typestate analysis in order to statically prevent use-after-free or enforce ownership transfer? edit: apparently, yes: [https://github.com/bhuztez/borrow](https://github.com/bhuztez/borrow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(writer<int>)` is non-dependent. That means that `wrapper<int>` is found in first phase lookup, when `f` is parsed (once).

`sizeof(writer<Tag>)`, on the other hand, is dependent on `Tag`. Thus, its lookup is deferred until phase two, when `f` is instantiated (at each of its call sites).

Comment: Yes. The first call on f returned 1. writer<int> is instantiated before the instantiation of f. Thanks